# Does IOS cap iframe processing power / painting of animations?

Tags: css, ios, animation, iframe

I have a very simple animation that's running and working in our preview tool, but not in the iframe on a webpage.

https://www.triplem.com.au/story/chaz-mostert-s-ford-mustang-declared-a-write-off-following-top-10-shootout-crash-150217

If you open this up in safari in IOS 12 (simulator or real device) it doesn't play the animations.

I'm wondering if there's a quirk where we have to add an attribute the iframe to allow it to repaint? even if I add `$('.some-elment').css('background', 'red')` it doesn't apply it to the dom as inline styles.

Is there anything anyone can think of?

Here's a preview of the animations working:

https://create.playground.xyz/sefayo/quiet?pos=header-ad&size=320x50&show-engagements=true